# How to block all the MessageBox.Show() from my WPF program?

Tags: wpf

Some of my referenced dlls have some MessageBox will show up sometimes, which is not desired in my program. So I want to block all the MessagBox from showing up in my WPF program. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You can view the byte code and remove the MessageBox.Show commands. As far as I know there is no other solution. I found a link which may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657606/is-it-possible-to-block-message-box-from-existing-dll

Comment: You could write a tight loop that wakes up every ~500ms and checks for the existence of a Window containing an OK button; if it finds one, send a msg to the button... a hack to be sure ... and if there's a valid MessageBox, it's going to get clobbered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent a third party library from displaying a MessageBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179672/how-can-i-prevent-a-third-party-library-from-displaying-a-messagebox)